# Secondary sort - leave it to Hadoop framework or do it yourself in reducer

Tags: sorting, hadoop

I read about secondary sorting, where there is a need to sort not only be key, but also by part of value, for each of the keys.

There are two ways to do this:

- Cache values in reducer for each key and sort the values yourself
- Leave the job to Hadoop framework, by specifying custom Comparator, Partitioner...all that you need to enable not only to sort by key, but also by value

My question is, when would you recommend first and when the second approach?

As I currently see it - if the framework already performs sorting, why not sort it by key and value at the same time...please correct me if there is some side-effect. For example, which should be faster?

I understand that the biggest problem of "in-Reducer sorting" is the number of records, but I would like to get the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding about secondary sort is correct. Before answering the given 2 scenarios, I would like to let you know what happen before the reduce() method of Reducer called.

Every reducer copies its relevant partitioned results from all mappers and stores in the reducer's disk as multiple spill files. A background thread merges all these spill files and creates a single sorted file.

The records in the final sinlge sorted file are first sorted by the natural key. Then the records of every key are internally sorted by the grouping key(secondar sorting), if it is configured.

So the decision to decide when to use the given 2 scenarios is depends on how much amount of reords are there in the single sorted file for a given key. The reduce method reads the all the values of a key one by one from single sorted file through the iterable reference given in the reduce() method.

If any java sorting collection such as TreeSet/TreeMap is capable of storing all the values of a key , provided the size of the java collection doesn't blow the JVM heap memory of reducer, then you may skip secondary sorting and you may use the Java sorting collection itself to achieve the sorting order that you prefer.

Incase, if the JVM heap memory for java sorting collections are not sufficient to store all the values of a key, then you should prefer the Mapreduce's custom secondary sorting which would sort the keys (natural sort) and sort all values of a key internally (secondary sort)  in the disk merge/sort phase of the single sorted file creation phase , and would pass the values in the prepared sorted order to the reduce method for a every key.

Comment: But is there any difference in performance? It seems also more efficient (faster) to use Hadoop framework, since it already performs sorting...is it really like that? Or is there any reason why in reduce sorting could be faster? I understand that there is an overhead in writing additional code, but I'm willing to do that, if it pays off.

Comment: secondary sorting is efficient, robust and easy as far as I observed. The performance is good with secodary sort since the most part of the sort done by a background thread in reducer during the shuffle/sort phase, and the reduce() method doesn't have to spend memory and execution load to sort the values for every key using collections where it could simply process the records as they come in pre-sorted order.